# Isn't it nearly impossible to use Azure Application Insights Auto Instrumentations for .NET?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to enable Azure Application Insights Auto Instrumentation for my existing ASP.NET web application hosted on App Service. It does not work, so I try to investigate and found this section from  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-monitor/app-insights/auto-instrumentation-troubleshoot?source=recommendations

> ## A diagnostics library was detected
>
> Auto-instrumentation fails if it detects the following libraries:
>
> `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource`
> `Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation`
> `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights`
>
> These libraries must be removed for auto-instrumentation to succeed.

In my case, my web application has a dependency on `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource`. But to my surprise, this library is a transitive dependency for `Azure.Core`, and most of the sdks to connnect with Azure services have a dependency on `Azure.Core`. And it is very unlikely that we want to deploy a web app on Azure without connecting to Azure services.

So does this mean that it is nearly impossible to use the auto instrumentation on a non-trivial app?

Comment: I think so. On the other hand, adding the Nuget package, passing the connection string and write a single line of code to init the package is hardly any work so you might be better off just doing that.

Comment: Yes, I do agree with Peter Bons. In this case it is advised to add Application Insights manually, it will not take much time and configuration can be done easily.

Comment: What is the .NET Version you are using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Isn't it nearly impossible to use Azure Application Insights Auto Instrumentations for .NET?

Thanks @Peter Bons for the comment.

As per this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps-net-core?tabs=Windows%2Clinux#enable-auto-instrumentation-monitoring), Auto Instrumentation is supported for

> Windows - .NET Core LTS
> Linux - Only ASP.NET Core 6.0.

Please check the   auto-instrumentation supported [environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/codeless-overview#supported-environments-languages-and-resource-providers).

It is not impossible, but Auto-Instrumentation may not track all the required telemetry data as you have specified.

To avoid all this, it is advised to configure the `Application Insights` Manually.

- Auto-Instrumentation works well when you you want to track data for easy and small Application.
- If you want to track any custom events and metrics, then better to go with manual Application Insights.

In `appsettings.json` file add the `ApplicationInsights ConnectionString`.

Refer the below links

- [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73566848/19648279) to configure ApplicationInsights manually in `.NET Core` Applications.
- [Azure Application Insights for ASP.Net Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net)