# Lots of n/a critical trace message in Azure application insights

Tags: azure, logging, azure-application-insights

I have dotnet core web application hosted in Azure and using application insights for logging.
I found I have abnormal amount of n/a critical trace message, like around 11k in just 1 min. Anyone has encountered this issue in application insights?
[image]

library:

- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore Version=2.15.0
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector Version=2.15.0
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DiagnosticSourceListener Version=2.15.0
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.EventSourceListener Version=2.15.0
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener Version=2.15.0
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer Version=2.15.0
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting Version=2.2.7

dotnet runtime:
netcoreapp3.1

I have configured application insights at below.

```
public static IWebHostBuilder UseLoggingWithAppInsights(this IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(applicationInsightsInstrumentKey);
    });

    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    IWebHostEnvironment host = provider.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
    IHttpContextAccessor context = provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

    TelemetryConfiguration.Active.EnableTelemetry(applicationInsightsInstrumentKey, appName, telemetryDetails, telemetrySettings, context, host);

    TelemetryConfiguration config = provider.GetService<TelemetryConfiguration>() ?? TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();

    TelemetryConfiguration.Active.FireTraceToSeeIfActive();
    config.FireTraceToSeeIfActive();

    builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        var instrumentationKey = context.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey");
        
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey)
            || TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey != instrumentationKey)
        {
            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey;
        }

        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        Util.StaticApplicationLogging.LoggerFactory = provider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
    });

    builder.ConfigureLogging((builderContext, loggingBuilder) =>
    {
        loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(builderContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    });

    return builder;
}
```

Comment: Please share your `appsettings.jsn` file.

Comment: @Harshitha which setting property do you want to look into? if appinsight, ApplicationInsightsBase:
  InstrumentationKey: ${EnvironmentValues:ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey}

Comment: What does your Logging => LogLevel setting have ?

Comment: Refer this [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73534404/logs-not-getting-written-to-applicationinsights/73566848#73566848) to configure ApplicationInsights in .NET Core.

Comment: Using 'TelemetryConfiguration.Active` is not recommended in .NET Core.

Comment: @Harshitha Serilog:
  Properties:
    Application: ${ApplicationData:ApplicationContainerName}
  MinimumLevel:
    Default: Information
    Override:
      Microsoft: Warning
      System: Warning
  Enrich:
    - FromLogContext

Comment: What exactly you want to log ?

Comment: @Harshitha currently it is logging error, each API call information, queue msg, etc. Just that n/a trace message i do not know what it is for and where was it coming from, and it is taking huge amount of space.

Comment: `{ 
  "Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    //"InstrmentationKey": "YourInstrumentationKey",
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=a23d17fa-8c1e-40b1-918e-14d8915946d4;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
  }
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252868/discussion-between-harshitha-and-endlesscalm).

Answer (score 0):

> Lots of n/a critical trace message in Azure application insights

The reason for this issue can be the incorrect configuration in `appsettings.json` file.

And the code which you have used is not recommended in `.NET Core` Applications.

```cs
 TelemetryConfiguration.Active.EnableTelemetry(applicationInsightsInstrumentKey, appName, telemetryDetails, telemetrySettings, context, host);
```

[image]

- Reduce the severity level of the messages, this can be done by setting only the log levels which are required.

***My Initial `appsettings.json` file.***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "AppInsightsConnString"
  }
}
```

- With the above `appsettings`  only `Error`,`Critical` and `Warning` messages are shown.
- To Log `Information` ,`Debug`  and `Exception` messages few changes have to be done in `appsettings.json` file.

***`appsettings.json` file:***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": { 
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=a******;IngestionEndpoint=https://*******8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://*******.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
  }
}
```

- Make sure all the packages are latest and updated.

***`.csproj` file:***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DiagnosticSourceListener" Version="2.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.EventSourceListener" Version="2.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener" Version="2.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.2.7" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

***`Startup.cs` file:***

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
           services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }
       
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");          
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

***Application Insights Traces:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: without touching existing configuration and codes, is it possible to just filter out those critical n/a trace message?