# Time delay or refresh of telemetry in App insights?

Tags: azure-application-insights

Have a asp.net website running in Azure and Im also running Visual Studio locally, trying to get some activity to show in the Azure portal in the logs.  For some reason it appears that not all requests are being sent up.  Just clicking through several pages in the deployed app, as well as locally, and after waiting 5,10 and 30 min, I still dont see the activity I started. I confirmed with my admin on the key Im using is correct.  What else can I check?

Querying the logs:
requests | where name contains "my-controller-here"

Or simply just browsing requests over the last 4 hours, I dont see the requests I initiated.  I see some other requests that have been made but nowhere near what should be seen, nor the requests I made.

In my appsettings file:

```
ApplicationInsights": {
   "InstrumentationKey":"key-val-here"
}
```

Ive also tried setting
"APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY":"key-val-here"

Comment: What are the requests you are checking for ? You have delay in traces or you are unable to them at all ?

Comment: What is the version of your App? Your configuration is not complete.You need to add the loglevel as well.

Comment: Please share your code where you are sending requests.

Answer (score 0):

> Time delay or refresh of telemetry in App insights?

- Yes, based on the request sent there will be some delay for few min in viewing the logs in Application Insights. But it will not last for hours.
- `appsettings.json` can be configured either with  `InstrumentationKey` or `ConnectionString`.
- Initially I haven't set any log level in the configuration. I have set the `LogInformation` message in `Program.cs` file.

```cs
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
var app = builder.Build();
app.Logger.LogInformation("Log Info from Program.cs file");
```

- When I run my application, I can see the trace in my local Console but not in the Application Insights - Transaction Search.

[image]

***Without LogLevel:***

[image]

***With LogLevel:***
[image]

[image]

- There might be issue with your configuration. Once set the Log Levels and try to check the logs.

Refer this [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73566848/19648279) to set the Log Levels in `appsettings.json` file.