# .NET 8 OpenTelemetry ApplicationInsights log level

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-application-insights, open-telemetry

I started using OpenTelemetry in my .NET project with AppInsights. But I don't understand how to set `LogLevel` for `ILogger` now. It used to be in **appsettings.json**.

Here's how I use OpenTelemetry in .NET:

```
HostApplicationBuilder builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false).AddJsonFile("appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", false);

ConfigureLogging(builder);

...

static void ConfigureLogging(IHostApplicationBuilder hostApplicationBuilder)
{
    hostApplicationBuilder.Services.AddLogging();
    hostApplicationBuilder.Logging.ClearProviders();

    hostApplicationBuilder.Logging.AddConsole();
    hostApplicationBuilder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry().UseAzureMonitor();
}
```

and here's the `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "AzureMonitor": {
    "ConnectionString": "..."
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to set `LogLevel = Warning` for OpenTelemetry only (basically, for AppInsights only). Where should I put this setting in `appsettings.json` file?

## Update

I guess my question is - when using OpenTelemetry, how `LogLevel` is set in the configuration? For example, I need to set `LogLevel = Information` for Console, **and** I need to set a different `LogLevel = Warning` for OpenTelemetry (which is ApplicationInsights). How do I do that?

Comment: Iam able to log Warning messages with this configuration itself.

Comment: Can you please be more clear about your ask.What you want to log.

Comment: Check this [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73566848/19648279) configuration once.

Answer (score 0):

I guess most developers would just stick with the classic SDK for now. However, after a brief research, I was able to find the alias in OpenTelemetry's [doc](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/tree/main/docs/logs/customizing-the-sdk). The alias is just **"OpenTelemetry"**.

A sample config(tested working) would be:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Error",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Error"
    },
    "OpenTelemetry": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

By the way, you can always find the alias of any correctly implemented custom logger provider in its `ProviderAliasAttribute`, see [OpenTelemetryLoggerProvider.cs](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/af57de2b017a09a85b3bd4323d7b01b0174b5742/src/OpenTelemetry/Logs/ILogger/OpenTelemetryLoggerProvider.cs#L16)