# Azure App Service Application Insights no longer showing request data

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-appservice

Was working all fine then I published a code update via Visual Studio and now no longer get any request data. The Overview page in the Azure Portal just shows flatlined graphs and Live Metrics has the message "Not available: couldn't connect to your application"

This a .NET 8 Asp.Net Core app

What I can see though is under Transaction Search it will show TRACE messages, just nothing else.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your configuration file. How you have configured Application Insights?

Comment: Please refer this [SOthread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73566848/19648279) which I have answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Live metrics in the Application Insights will be enabled by default when you deploy the App to Azure App Service.

[image]

- I have configured Application Insights from `Connected Services`.

[image]

- If you want to enable `Live metrics` manually, you can do it from the deployed `App Service` => `Application Insights`
- Click on `Turn on the Application Insights`.

[image]

[image]

- As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/live-stream?tabs=dotnet6#enable-live-metrics-by-using-code-for-any-net-application) you can even enable it from code.
- I can see both requests and traces in Transaction search.

[image]

Refer `appsetting.json` file setting in this [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73566848/19648279) for AppInsights Configuration.

Comment: I think the problem might have been I was using SeriLog. Once I removed all that and just went back to the default Asp.Net Core logging it all working ok now.