# Not able to view the logs for hosted WebApp in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-log-analytics, azure-webapps

I have a ASP.NET Core MVC app in Azure.  I have implemented the logs in the MVC where I want to capure informational logs and error log.  So when needed developer can view the logs in Azure portal.   In order to do so, I followed some tutorial and got help from stackoverflow forum and tried different ways and multiple times but I am not able to see the error log in filesystem.  My goal is the view the file for information log and error using file system.  As there are many ways to view the error but I am not want to just see the error but the information as well and that I want to see in the file.  Please see below images for the code and setting in Azure.

--Appsetting.json
[image]

--Code to capture the error. This method call another method whichly surely thows an error. I used diagonostic jsut to try if that can capture informaiton in log file. However, I have other code that does have code for _loggger.logInformation("Information goes here")

[image]

--Turned on the FileSystem loggin in Azure after the deployment was completed.
[image]

--Kudu view for the file under   home>Logfiles>Application.  Beside the view, I checked for the files in other folders just incase if file was created at other location but no file was created.

[image]

So please help.

Comment: What is the version of your App?

Comment: Try with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73566848/19648279) configuration once.

Comment: You have added logging for ApplicationInsights,but I don't see Instrumentation Key or Application Insights Connection String in appsettings.json file.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to log the Information and Error messages with the same [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#azure-app-service) which you have shared.

- Instead of  `(ex.Message,"Text")` , set the Error message as `(ex,"Text")`.
- You can remove `builder.Logging.AddApplicationInsights();`  line of code if you don't want to check the logs in Application Insights.

***My `Controller.cs`:***

```cs
 [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
 public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
 {
     try
     {
         _logger.LogInformation("Log Information from API");
         throw new Exception();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         _logger.LogError(ex.Message, "Errorrrrrrrrrrrr");
         _logger.LogError(ex.StackTrace);
         _logger.LogError("DEBUG: A NEW EXCEPTION without Ex");
         _logger.LogError(ex, "DEBUG ERROR: Error EXCEPTION with ex");
     }
     -----
 }
```

***My `appsettings.json` file:***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

- After deploying the App to Azure App Service, In  `App Service logs` enable the `Application logging`,`Web server logging`,`Detailed error messages` and `Failed request tracing` as shown below.

[image]

- Execute the request from the Controller.
- Now check for the logs and traces in LogStream.

[image]

> Kudu view for the file under home>Logfiles>Application

- Log file with name `Diagnostics-Logs`(which I have set in `Program.cs` file) will be created under `C:\home\LogFiles\Application` folder.

[image]

- The logs which you have seen in `LogStream` can be seen here as well.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Harshitha,  I am still not only I am able to create a file but also I am not able to see the error or information logs in Logs stream. I will do further search and hopefully when it is resolve I will update.  Thanks

Comment: Can you share your exact code which you are trying?